# Yii2-Time not saved while creating a record

Tags: php, datetime, model, yii2

I am creating a record in which there is a `created_at (datetime)` field. While saving the record only date is saved into the Database.

**Create Action**

```
 public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Meters();


    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

The saved date is like `2017-12-03 00:00:00`. Also I have used `var_dump($model)` and I get on date not time.

I don't know what I am missing.

**Update 1**

My model is

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['meter_msn','description','meter_status','historic'],'required'],
        //[['meter_msn'],'unique','message'=>'This meter already exists'],
        [['created_at', 'updated_at','comments'], 'safe'],
        [['created_by', 'updated_by', 'status','historic'], 'integer'],
        [['description', 'meter_msn'], 'string', 'max' => 200],
    ];
}

/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function attributeLabels()
{
    return [
        'id' => 'ID',
        'description' => 'Name',
        'meter_msn' => 'Meter MSN',
        'created_at' => 'Created At',
        'updated_at' => 'Updated At',
        'created_by' => 'Created By',
        'updated_by' => 'Updated By',
        'status' => 'Status',
        'comments' => 'Comments',
        'meter_status' => 'Meter Status',
        'historic'=> 'Version'
    ];
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share data in your model after `load()` and your model class aswell?

Comment: Show your model definition `Meters`

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid kindly see the update

Comment: @Yupik I have update my question

Comment: @MrFaisal put here post data too. Right now, you don't have behavior to handle `created_at` time, so if you're not sending it in post data - there wont be any data in your database.

Comment: @MrFaisal For `created_at` column set default value to current date and time for reference [have a look](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html#default)

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid set date time in database ?

Comment: @MrFaisal No in your model see the reference link of official documentation

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to your model:

```
 public function beforeSave($insert) 
{
    if($this->isNewRecord) {
        $this->created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }else {
        $this->updated_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    }
    return parent::beforeSave($insert);
}
```

Comment: It says method `beforeSave` not found in `yi\web\Controller`

Comment: did you put it in your model

Comment: I put it in the controller but now I put it in my `Model` and same result only date is displaying and time as zero(0)

Comment: what is the format for the date field in your database table

Comment: is `updated_at` also having time as zero when you update a record

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161150/discussion-between-mr-faisal-and-kalu).